# Is there any way to stop the console logs in universal SSR build?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular-universal

I had a problem regarding the printing of console logs in server console while i am running my application in angular universal SSR.

i tried some of the solutions in internet. it is working at browser level it is not working at server level. below there is code what i tried. i placed the below code in main.ts file but nothing gonna worked at SSR level.

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
  if(window){
    window.console.log=function(){};
  } else {
    console.log=function(){};
  }
}
```

the above code works fine with browser and it is not working at server console. while i am running this command npm run serve:ssr

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work.

Are you sure that is building in production? put a console.log before the `enableProdMode();` to make sure that the code is entering through there. (And another just after to see that consoles doesn't show anymore)

```
if (environment.production) {
  console.log('Enabling prod');
  enableProdMode();
  if(window){
    window.console.log=function(){};
  } else {
    console.log=function(){};
  }
   console.log('Production enabled, this console.log won't appear');
}
```

I have this command in my package.json to try it:

```
 "build:ssr:serve": "ng build --prod && ng run ssr:server:production && node dist/server"
```

Then execute it with: `npm run build:ssr:serve` and the second console.log doesn't show.

Comment: this is my scripts in package/json file

Comment: "build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run compile:server",

Comment: "serve:ssr": "node dist/server",

Comment: that  console.log('Enabling prod'); is not printing

Comment: this console.log('Enabling prod'); is printing in browser console not printing in server console

Comment: can u show me your complete scripts in package.json file so that i will find my mistake

Comment: The enabling prod should appear. The one who shouldn't appear it's the other one :  `'Production enabled, this console.log won't appear'`

Comment: Check that in your `environment.prod.ts` you have the line of production:true `export const environment = {
  production: true
};`

Comment: Also check that in the `angular.json` you have the environment replacement: 
    `"configurations": {            "production": {              "fileReplacements": [                
                 "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",                  "with":"src/environments/environment.prod.ts"  } ...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191522/discussion-between-daniel-pineiro-and-santosh-raju).